# Multi-selection with different color for each selected object

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to build a feature to select multiple objects with a different colour to differentiate their status.

Is this possible to have multi-selection in a different colour?

Comment: i hope you have got the solution by now. If you have anymore doubt, please ask. if the information provided was useful, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some sort of mapping to do this elegantly. If you have an object that describes a dbId and a status you can map from status to color automaticly. You can use enums for more type safety but this is ommited for this example.:

typescript:

```
interface ItemStatus{
    dbId: number,
    status: string
}
let statusColors: { [key: string]: string; } = {};
statusColors['INITIATED'] = "#0000FF";
statusColors['COMPLETED'] = "#00FF00";
statusColors['FAILED'] = "#FF0000";

let items: ItemStatus[] = [{ dbId: 1, status: 'INITIATED' }, { dbId: 2, status: 'COMPLETED' }]

// add color to items
setColor(items)
// select colored items
this.viewer.select(items.map(x => x.dbId));

function setColor(items: ItemStatus[]) : void{
    items.forEach(item => {
        // setThemingColor requires we a THREE.Vector4 so we have to provide it
        // using our hex color we generate a THREE.Color object and assign the 4th value of THREE.Vector4 manually to 1
        let color = new THREE.Color(statusColors[item.status]);
        this.viewer.setThemingColor(item.dbId, new THREE.Vector4(color.r, color.g, color.b, 1))
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's working but it doesn't show the colour change when an object is already selected with the default selection colour. Do you have any idea to change colour for a selected object?

Comment: setThemingColor blends the origional color with the color specified. I think the select command does not infact override the set color but it is very hard to see with non contrasting colors. You could also override the default selection color to be very light and contrasty, take a look at [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setselectioncolor-color-selectiontype)

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the different color for different dbid in

`viewer.setThemingColor();`

Ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive

Related helpful blogs:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/happy-easter-setthemingcolor-model-material
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/revisiting-viewers-theming-coloring-selective-cancelling-deferred-rendering-and-recursive